# Possibly remove ListSelectionListener before clearing Jtable (runtime)?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have written a ListSelectionEvent for my jTable.

It works to take values from specific cells and put the value into the cells corresponding jTextField.

So, I upload a CSV file to the jTable. It loads.

I click the button at the bottom labeled "Clear Table". The table is cleared and a new blank row is made (I couldn't get around doing this. Otherwise it wouldn't let me load another CSV file)

My problem :: I load another CSV File. It loads. I select a row, the listSelectionEvent fires, and executes as it should. I click "Clear Table" and it throws this Exception.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

After this the program starts bugging out and needs to be closed. The jTable does clear when the window is resized.

Thanks in advance for help with this.

JB

Comment: I made another button "Delete Row"
The Event:

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
model.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
jtable1.setModel(model);

This button causes the same Execption to be thrown.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with hardcoded value (as local variable) for DefaultTableModel, there are four possible issues, wrong notifiers in TableModel, replacing JTable, code lines inside ListSelectionListener, some ZOO in Renderer, or their free_styled combinations, meaning runnable, compilable code, btw tons on this forum

Comment: please edit your question and the additional details (instead of trying it in an comment which is near-to unreadable)

Answer (score 2):

Before you do any calls to the model using `table.getSelectedRow()`, you should first check if this value is >= 0.

Comment: jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            String s = "";

            java.lang.Object key = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),0);
            String a = key.toString();

            if ("".equals(a)||a.equals(null)){
                jTextField1.setText(s);
            }
            else {
                jTextField1.setText(a);
            }

Comment: What is missing here?

Thanks for your replys.

Comment: if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() >= 0) {...do your stuff} otherwise do nothing. A selected row = -1 means no selection.

Comment: You're amazing. You helped me put the final touch on my program.